# Best way to implement Bitcode?

Tags: ios, size, llvm, bitcode, app-thinning

I have some questions regarding Bitcode since there aren't many documentations about it.

From what I understand (correct me if I’m wrong), the main benefits of Bitcode are:

1. Reduce the size of the app (not the ipa), since it is a part of App
   Thinning.
2. Recompilation automation since Apple will recompile the app if there
   are updates / improvements to the compiler.

I have finally tried to enable Bitcode on iOS, but after enabling Bitcode the download size of my app stayed the same and the install size was only reduced by 1 mb (less than 0.01%). So I have some questions:

1. Is there any factor that can affect Bitcode effectiveness? (for ex.
   static / dynamic framework, etc) If yes, what is the best way to
   implement Bitcode?
2. With the result that I have told you, is it worth to enable Bitcode?
   Is there any other main reason to enable Bitcode?

Thank you very much.

**Update**
From a quick experiment on an empty project, first with dynamic frameworks and then with static libraries, I found that Bitcode reduced the size by 19,75% on the project with dynamic frameworks, and only 2,7% on the project with static libraries.

Comment: How are you checking the size of the downloaded app?  Are you downloading it on a device?

Comment: @Paulw11 From iTunes Connect. I uploaded it and check the size estimation.